# Passing text box text from a userform to a sheet using MVP pattern

Tags: excel, vba, properties, userform

Ok... So I am trying to wrap my head around properties. I have done a ton of googling but really need to try myself to fully understand. I have 3 components:

1. I have a UserForm: "frmView1"
2. I have a class module: "clsPresenter1"
3. I have a regular module: "modModel1"

My UserForm has a txtbox "TextBox1" and here is the userform code:

```
Option Explicit

'View (The V in MVP)

Public Event OnTxtBoxChange()

Public Property Get TxtBoxInfo() As String

    TxtBoxInfo = TextBox1.Text

End Property

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

    RaiseEvent OnTxtBoxChange

End Sub
```

My Class module:

```
Option Explicit

'Presenter Class (The P in MVP)
'Implements Business Logic

Private WithEvents objUserForm As frmView1

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

    Set objUserForm = New frmView1

End Sub

Public Sub TxtBoxContent()

    objUserForm.TxtBoxInfo

End Sub

Private Sub objUserForm_OnTxtBoxChange()

    DoSomething

End Sub
```

My regular module:

```
Option Explicit

'Model Module (The M in MVP)
'Business Logic
Private objPresenter As clsPresenter1

Public Sub DoSomething()

    Sheet1.Cells.Clear
    Sheet1.Cells(3, 3) = objPresenter.TxtBoxContent   

End Sub
```

So this is a shortened version to simplify my question. In reality I have code to show the form and close the form and a few other things that are working fine. But my question is... How do I pass whatever the user types in the txt box to the worksheet? I keep getting:

```
Compile error: Expected Function or variable
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok... So I may have figured it out... I changed:

```
Public Sub TxtBoxContent()

    objUserForm.TxtBoxInfo

End Sub
```

To:

```
Public Function TxtBoxContent() As String

    TxtBoxContent = objUserForm.TxtBoxInfo

End Function
```

This seems to work... Please let me know if this is not the correct way...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is actually the correct way? Again changing:

```
Public Sub TxtBoxContent()

    objUserForm.TxtBoxInfo

End Sub
```

To:

```
Public Property Get TxtBoxContent() As String

    TxtBoxContent = objUserForm.TxtBoxInfo

End Property
```

Again this seems to work... But why would I ever use a function in my class module ("presenter") if I could always use a property instead?

Comment: You shouldn't use answers to comment/change your own question - please read [help] to understand how SO is working